# htaccess setting the mimetype for a single file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

In an .htaccess file one might set the mimetype for a given extension like:

```
AddType application/javascript .js
```

How would one set the mimetype for a single file instead of an extension?  I have one Javascript that needs a different mimetype than other Javascript files in the same folder.

```
AddType application/javascript .js
AddType application/ecmascript specialfile.js
```

The second line does not work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `<files>` container to match the file's name before adding a type for it:

```
<Files specialfile.js>
    AddType application/ecmascript .js
</Files>
```

Comment: I tried it, but when I open that address, the browser ask me to download that file. For example, if I use `<Files hello.html>`, when I open `http://mysever.com/hello.html` the browser downloads hello.html instead of open it

Comment: @DeLac If the _browser_ does not understand the mime-type you have stated (eg. `application/ecmascript` in this example) then the browser will prompt to download it.

Comment: More generally, since you are using a `<Files>` container I would perhaps choose to use a `ForceType` directive rather than `AddType` to ensure that all files that match the _condition_ are served the appropriate mime-type. eg. `ForceType application/ecmascript`