# Specify mime type of php file as application/javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to specify the MIME type of a PHP file as `application/javascript`? I have a PHP file that outputs some JavaScript. When strict MIME type checking is enabled, the browser reports an error:

> "Refused to execute script from *.php' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Adding this to the PHP file doesn't help:

```
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
```

Here is my code:

```
<?
  header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
  include ("../admin/config.php");
  include ("../custom_functions.php");
?>
var availableTags = ["BBCD"
<? 
  $prods=decode_prods();
  foreach($prods as $key=>$val){  
?>
, "
<?
  $prods[$key][name] = preg_replace("/(\015\012)|(\015)|(\012)/","",$prods[$key][name]); 
  trim($prods[$key][name]);
  $prods[$key][name]= str_replace("&", "and", $prods[$key][name]);
  $prods[$key][name]= str_replace('"', '', $prods[$key][name]);
  echo $prods[$key][name];
?>
"
<? } ?>
];
```

I tried adding this to `.htaccess` after reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628826/htaccess-setting-the-mimetype-for-a-single-file) - but it didn't help.

```
<Files /js/auto.php>
AddType application/javascript .js
</Files>
```

Comment: Show the code please

Comment: The code displayed is *all* the code, correct? The reason I ask is you cannot change headers once output has started. If output isn't started before what's displayed here, then what browser are you using and are you sure the header isn't being changed in your included files?

Comment: @bugfroggy Thats all the code in auto.php. Its called from template file like this:  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/auto.php"></script>

Comment: That could be your issue. Use `application/javascript` as `text/javascript` is deprecated. I don't see why this would cause it but worth a try.

Comment: @bugfroggy good point  - but no that didn't help.

Answer (score 7):

you mean something like that?

```
header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
```